# Problem with AddTo and SubtractFrom in function definition

Tags: functions

I have written a function

`roulette[n_,b_]:= With[{money=100,bins=Range[38]},Table[If[b == RandomChoice[bins], money += 35, money -= 1], {n}]]`

to simulate n games of American roulette with a bet on b. The functions SubtractFrom and AddTo are not working as intended.

`roulette[100,5]` returns the result

SubtractFrom: `100` is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed and similarly for AddTo. Is there a way to use += and -= within the function roulette?

Note: If I do not use the localized environment and define money = 100 external to the function roulette, it will run the simulation once, but this is problematic when I try to use roulette with starting money=100 in more complicated ways.

Comment: Replace `With` with `Module`?

Comment: I think you want "Module" and not "With"

Comment: Module worked out great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could just avoid those intermediate variables altogether:

```
RouletteWinLoss[betCount_] := RandomChoice[{37, 1} -> {-1, 35}, betCount];
RouletteSequence[start_, betCount_] := 
  Accumulate[Prepend[RouletteWinLoss[betCount], start]];
RouletteSequence[100, 30]
```

`{100,99,98,97,96,95,94,93,92,91,90,89,88,87,122,121,120,119,118,117,116,115,150,149,148,147,146,145,144,143,142}`

(Randomly got lucky!)

Comment: Wolfram is strong. Many ways to solve the same problem. Your example doesn't address the problem with += or -= and the With[] function but shows the versatility of the language. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 1):

Using **`FoldList`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[3];
roulette[n_, b_] := FoldList[
  #1 + If[#2 == b, 35, -1] &
  , 100
  , RandomChoice[Range[38], {n}]
  ]

roulette[100, 5]
```

> ```
> {100, 99, 98, 97, 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 84, \
>     83, 82, 81, 116, 115, 150, 149, 148, 147, 146, 145, 180, 179, 178, \
>     177, 176, 175, 174, 173, 172, 171, 170, 169, 204, 203, 202, 201, 200, \
>     199, 198, 197, 196, 195, 194, 193, 192, 191, 190, 189, 188, 187, 186, \
>     185, 184, 183, 182, 181, 216, 215, 214, 213, 212, 211, 210, 209, 208, \
>     207, 206, 205, 204, 203, 202, 201, 200, 199, 198, 197, 196, 195, 194, \
>     193, 192, 191, 190, 189, 188, 187, 186, 185, 184, 183, 182, 181, 180}
> ```

Further parametrization can be done as needed.